# Multi charts in C# Plotly - how to create?

Tags: c#, plotly

How can I create multi chart in Plotly in C# ?

Chart.Line(data).Show() produces only ONE line in chart.
data - is IEnumerable of something or Tuple, say float.

Is there a way to prepare these data, say, IEnumerable to  have many lines (or bars for Chart.Bar(data)) -  in one chart ?
It is obvious functionality in Python.
Probably I'm missing something.

OK. I found the answer Myself..:
The point is to use Chart.Plot with LIST of scatters :

```
List<Scatter> scatters = new List<Scatter>();
   scatters.Add(scatter_i1); scatters.Add(scatter_i2); scatters.Add(scatter_i3);
```

where scatter is sth like :

```
 var scatter_i = new Scatter() {
                x = Enumerable.Range(1, 500),
                y = housingAges,   //  y = df1.Columns["Ages"],
                mode = "lines+markers",
            };

 var chart = Chart.Plot(scatters,chart_layout);
 chart.Show();
```

Answer (score 1):

OK. I found the answer Myself..: The point is to use Chart.Plot with LIST of scatters :

```
List<Scatter> scatters = new List<Scatter>();
   scatters.Add(scatter_i1); scatters.Add(scatter_i2); scatters.Add(scatter_i3);
```

where scatter is sth like :

```
var scatter_i = new Scatter() {
                x = Enumerable.Range(1, 500),
                y = housingAges,   //  y = df1.Columns["Ages"],
                mode = "lines+markers",
            };

 var chart = Chart.Plot(scatters,chart_layout);
 chart.Show();
```